# Google Kubernetes Ingress show a status error even after fixing the issues

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I erroneously created a Kubernetes service with a TCP/UDP load balancing where in fact I needed an HTTP/S load balancing.

To fix the above issue, I created an ingress that pointed to my service. The ingress was to manage the HTTP/S with balancing and everything worked fine.

But as I didn't need the TCP/UDP load balancing anymore I deleted its corresponding service and created another one with the same name, but chose the service type "NodePorts" this time.

After some minutes my ingress recognized the new service (based on its name) and everything is working again.

However, I see the following error message for the ingress:
error while evaluating the ingress spec: could not find service "default/zapi-web"

How can I fix this status message at ingress?

[image: the error is beins shown event after ingress being OK]

Answer (score 0):

I think I could fix it: just edited the yaml, added some spaces and Saved :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the actions you performed in order to solve your issue? it would be very useful for the rest of the community with a similar problem. Please edit the answer.